# botbuilder-python dialogs and conversation flow

Tags: python, botframework, bots

I cannot find any docs or examples to create a dialog\waterfall conversations  in botbuilder-python. Is it not possible yet? I know it is in preview.
Has anyone tried to create bots with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BotFramework Python SDK is still in Preview, and, unfortunately, does not currently support Waterfall Dialogs. I have heard that the development team might be expanding the Python SDK in the near future, so be sure to check the [BotBuilder-Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python) repo for updates!